# 3D plot of prc::vegan

Tags: r, plot, 3d

In traditional plot of prc::vegan effectively the first rda axis is plotted as the y axis and time is the x axis. 
I am trying to recreate a 3D version of the prc using the 2nd rda axis as the z axis. I am not very familiar with 3D graphics but I tried to use scatterplot3D. 
I'd be grateful if there are better packages to present this data in a better way.

```
data(pyrifos)
week <- gl(11, 12, labels=c(-4, -1, 0.1, 1, 2, 4, 8, 12, 15, 19, 24))
treat <- factor(rep(c("A","B","C","D"), 33))

mod <- prc(pyrifos, dose, week)
plot(mod)  #this is the traditional prc graphic

prc= rda(pyrifos ~ treat * week + Condition(week), data = pyrifos)
#this is a manual form of the prc() function

scores_1st_axis = scores(prc)$sites[, 1]
site_score_2nd_axis = scores(prc)$sites[, 2]

dat= as.data.frame(cbind(week, treat, scores_1st_axis,site_score_2nd_axis))

cols = c("#fc8d59","#007be6", "#00a42d","#b8e186")
cols = cols[as.factor(dat$treat)]
dat= cbind(cols, dat)

# How can I plot this data in 3D format? 
#preferably an interactive rotating  graphic, 
# and/or with a line running through each 'treat' over time 
# to allow for better representation and interpretation

scatterplot3d(site_scores,site_score_2nd_axis,week, color = dat$cols)
```

Comment: Good 3D graphics can be plotted using the `plotly` package: https://plot.ly/r/3d-scatter-plots/